# Regex matching wrong optional group

Tags: regex, vb.net

I'm trying to match a time format. The time can be written with optional hours, minutes and milliseconds. The only required value is seconds. So all of these times are correctly written and should match.

```
10:11:12.123 '10 hours, 11 minutes, 12 seconds and 123 milliseconds
10:11:12     '10 hours, 11 minutes and 12 seconds
11:12.123    '11 minutes, 12 seconds and 123 milliseconds
11:12        '11 minutes and 12 seconds
12.123       '12 seconds and 123 milliseconds
12           '12 seconds
```

My regex looks like this: `(?:(?:(\d*):)?(?:(\d*):)?(\d*)(?:\.(\d*))?)`

I would like each group to correspond to the right value. So group 1 should always return hours, group 2 should always return minutes, etc... I tried this in [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/l7JAH3/1) but as you can see in those results group 1 is always preferred over group 2 when there are no hours in play. It matches the time `11:12` perfectly but it places `11` in group 1 telling me it's hours while it actually is minutes. That's no strange behavior because the minutes in this string matches group 1. But it is not what I want.

How to make sure that each group always corresponds to the right part of the time? Can I prioritize group 2 over group 1 in some way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may move the first optional group into the second one so that they were tried in an immediate succession within one greedy matching group:

```
(?:(?:(\d+):)?(\d+):)?(\d+)(?:\.(\d+))?
   ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/W2oLXi/1)

**Details**

- `(?:(?:(\d+):)?(\d+):)?` - an optional non-capturing group matching one or zero occurrences of:

  - `(?:(\d+):)?` - an optional non-capturing group matching and capturing into Group 1 any one or more digits and then just matching `:`
  - `(\d+)` - Group 2: one or more digits
  - `:` - a colon
- `(\d+)` - Group 3: one or more digits
- `(?:\.(\d+))?` - an optional non-capturing group matching a dot and then capturing into Group 4 one or more digits.